# How do split drawings from this without losing their dimension Autocad

Tags: autocad, technical-drawing, drawings

I have a dxf file converted to dwg (unit: millimeters). There are 6 different drawings in the same file, How do I split those to different sheet. I wanted to take their consumption, as they are going to cut from a rexin 1.4 x 1 meter(w x h).
So I want to fill each drawing to sheet and get count.

Guide me a method, I am currently trying with autocad as they support the dxf file
Currently am trying with PATCH.dxf file (8x13 sizes in there)

https://gofile.io/?c=FL2JGj

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple things on a single layout that you want to move to different layouts? You can create new layouts in an AutoCAD file, and copy and paste from the old layout to the new layouts however you like. When you said "fill each drawing", do you mean you are changing the scale of the drawings?

Comment: Actually I got how to split up, now stuck to arrange them. Like I want to fill a single drawing in 1400 x 1000 mm square. How do I actually set a drawing certain length from a reference point. Or how can I adjust dimension like, if it's 12mm away i want to make it 10mm.